# Problems in limiting the amount of characters displayed in the output of a parameter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, limit, ssrs-2008-r2

For the purposes of a report I need to display the parameters selected in that report. One of my parameters is a multi-select of filepaths that are split in the report's main query by commas ",". When i run the report and i want to display the parameters selected for that report I have to use the following expression in order to view my results without errors:

`=Join(Parameters!FilePath.Label,",")`

as this : `Parameters!FilePath.Label` would cause the report to show an error.

How can i keep this piece of code `=Join(Parameters!FilePath.Label,",")` but be able to limit it up to a certain number of characters so that my screen doesnt get overwhelmed when too many selections are made?

So this is the result i am currently getting if too many selections are made:

C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,

and I would like something to this effect:

C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example,C:/Desktop/Files/example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem and it is as follows:
`=Left((Join(Parameters!FilePath.Label,",")),500)&"..."`